Spring boot deprecation message Should be applied at the ObservationRegistry level meaning
My application uses the following Spring Boot property management.metrics.web.server.request.autotime.enabled. it's listed as deprecation in v3.2.6 with message Should be applied at the ObservationRegistry level. What does this message mean and how do I apply this property at the ObservationRegistry level.
Thanks!

The answer is in the comments of this question. Since it was given to me by someone else it doesn't feel right for me to post it here as an answer >_>

Update: the deprecation descriptions of these properties has been updated in this commit for Spring Boot 3.10.
